# perl : any module to manage toggle activation of certain feature in perl package/module

Tags: perl, module

I am currently developing a module which will have certain features disabled for web application and independent application.

The easiest approach will be to declare global variable to switch on/off these features:

```
#### package
package a:Features;

our $F1 = 0;
@EXPORT_OK = (F1);

sub new {
  ..........
  if ( $F1 == 1 ) {
    ...........
    ...........
  } 
}
```

Caller program

```
#main Program
use a:Features;
our $F1;
$F1 = 1;
```

Is there any better approach or a module that can manage the features in the module/package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with a global variable is that one cannot use your module several times as part of a larger program without causing evil actions at a distance.

Instead, make the interface object-objected, the option whether the module works as a Web app or not goes into the constructor.